# Is there a way to download only 1 python function from a module?

Tags: python, memory, geospatial

So I need to upload some python code and its conda environment to a shared Raspberry pi, and space is an issue. My environment comes out to 1.2GB, and includes just `geopandas, numpy, rasterio, rioxarray`. Since I only use `geopandas.read_file()` function from `geopandas` for example, is there a way to include only it and its "dependencies", in terms of functions/classes that it uses?

Comment: It's called tree shaking, [this package](https://github.com/sclabs/treeshaker) might help, haven't tried it myself